# WebRTC ICE not connecting with flask-login

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, webrtc

I've ported the WebRTC demo app to work with the flask framework.
the strange thing is that everything is working perfect when one of the users is not logged in.
but when I login both users, I don't get the onIceConnectionStateChanged = connected.
I don't see any connection between the two modules (I've kept the apprtc random number user)
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are testing this from Chrome. In Chrome you can type in "chrome://webrtc-internals" to get all of the info about your ICE connection and other webrtc related debug information. If you already know this, do you see that any errors on that page?

Couple of ideas: 
1. Make sure that setLocalDescription or setRemoteDescription steps succeed on both clients. 
2. Check and make sure that all of your ICE-related info(like STUN or TURN servers) are correctly specified.